# [cscan][error][scan_perform_scan] unable to set log callback for libhostscan.

Tags: windows-8, cisco-vpn-client

I'm attempting to connect to a cisco VPN using AnyConnect client, the 1st of part of which involves going to a website and loading Cisco Secure desktop to confirm that my machine is suitable. This check fails every time, however no feedback is given.

The only hint I can find is in the Event Viewer as follows:

> The description for Event ID 259 from source cscan cannot be found.
>   Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your
>   local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or
>   repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> [cscan][error][scan_perform_scan] unable to set log callback for
>   libhostscan.

However searching on-line for the string `unable to set log callback for libhostscan` returns 0 results so I'm utterly lost with where to look next.